# Error in Eclipse Neon 2 in workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

I have installed Android sdk and eclipse neon .2 for android developers. When I create android project and click finish, it gives this error. Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: dont use eclipse, https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK has not been setup properly inside your Eclipse environment.
Reinstalling using recommended settings might resolve this issue.
Android Studio 2.0 is the new recommended IDE for developing Android apps and is extremely easy to setup.
Link: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html